# C++ class interface to pass-through to another member variable

Tags: c++, class, reference

Let's say I have a class `Param` defined like this:

```
class Param {
public:
    std::vector<double> lb;
    std::vector<double> mid;
    std::vector<double> ub;
    int level;
};
```

The purpose of this class is to define lower- and upper-bounds (`lb` and `ub`, respectively) and a midpoint estimate for different parameters.  Assume that for a given object, `lb`, `mid`, and `ub` have the same number of elements.

Now, if `level<0`, I want to use the `lb` estimates.  If `level==0`, I want to use the `mid` estimates.  Otherwise (if `level>0`), I want to use the `ub` estimates.

**My question is**: how can I create a single member function (or something akin to a reference member variable) that will automatically "pass through" to the appropriate member `std::vector<double>` based on the value of `level`?

For example, if I have a function

`void f(const std::vector<double>& X);`

or

`void g(std::vector<double>& X);`

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Param myParam;
// set values of myParam.lb, myParam.mid, and myParam.ub, and myParam.level
f(myParam.__?__);
g(myParam.__?__);
```

Comment: Why is `level` a member of `Param` anyway?

Comment: @ChrisCulter because I may want to change which parameter estimates I'm using, and level reflects the estimates I'm using.  (Maybe I misunderstand your question...)

Comment: Obviously I don't know the context, but it seems like it doesn't need to be a persistent state that's tied to the data. Can it be just a local variable in whatever code is using a `Param`?

Comment: @ChrisCulter It definitely could be.  But there are 20 to 30 `Param`s, and different combinations of them are using different `level`s at one time.  The context is that the various `Param`s make up a mathematical model, and I need to perform sensitivity analysis over the model's parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add *cast operators* to your class:

```
class Param {
    //...

    operator std::vector<double>& () {
        if( level < 0 ) return lb;
        if( level > 0 ) return ub;
        return mid;
    }

    operator const std::vector<double>& () const {
        if( level < 0 ) return lb;
        if( level > 0 ) return ub;
        return mid;
    }
};
```

Now you can call like this:

```
f(myParam);
g(myParam);
```

Comment: That's awesome!  So are the `return` statements in your code creating another copy in memory of the returned items?

Comment: No, they're returning references.

Comment: No, they return a reference, because that is the type we are casting to.  Note the `&` in the cast operators.

Comment: Would the method you suggest work if I changed `lb`, `mid`, and `ub` to be private members?

Comment: Yes, it would still work, even though the return value provides an outsider with a reference into a private member.  The class still controls the private members and you can't access them directly from outside, but if it's happy to give outsiders a direct reference to them, that's okay.

Comment: Eek. This kind of thing should be used very sparingly. Not sure that the present use case warrants it. And best to mention that such an object is called a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple.

```
std::vector< double > & getBound() {
    if ( level < 0 ) return lb;
    if ( level == 0 ) return mid;
    return ub;
}
```

Add a `const` overload returning a `const &` reference if necessary.

I would recommend against doing anything trickier than this. If you want to get something from an object, mentioning a function is usually better than defining a function which is automatically called despite not being named.

(Note: I submitted this more than three hours ago, but connection difficulties delayed it, hence the redundancy.)